# Show Mobile Ads when User is Offline

Tags: android, ads, offline

I have tried to find some advertising companies that would be providing online advertising, but I have not found any one.

I think this possibility exists. Ads would downloaded when a user is online and when is offline it would appear in apps.

Do you have any experience with this issue?

---

A lot of people off wifi because of ads in a game.

What do you do to earn if a user is offline?

Comment: But what should happen when the user clicks on such an ad while he's offline? Usually, publishers are paid on a pay per click basis which isn't feasible when the user is offline. Paying per view seems more feasible to me. However, the user still wouldn't be able to interact, i.e., click on the ad to get to the advertisers content/page. I'd assume that this makes offline ads in a mobile device context mostly worthless. There might be exceptions, though, for ads which are more likely digital representations of typical offline ads like flyers.

Comment: It could be similar as in televisions. There is also impossible interact with ads. You could earn money only when you see a ad (interstitial, video). You would get money only for seeing add. Of course, per one show of a ad you would earn a much less as for example click to AdMob banner.

Another option is, that ads would show you in a browser and when you want download it, you must turn on your net connection. And then it would be accepted as click to a ad. Similar with online ads.